# Error when trying to use debugger in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I've installed all the gems needed to run the debugger in my Rails app, but I get the following error. I have `require 'ruby-debug'` in `development.rb`.

Error:

```
runnerw.exe C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/bin/rdebug-ide --debug --port 7339 --dispatcher-port 7340 -- C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/script/server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11.30.pre15) listens on 127.0.0.1:7339
Connected from 127.0.0.1
6616: Starting control thread
6616: Processing in control: b C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/app/controllers/editing_member_jobs_controller.rb:120
6616: <breakpointAdded no="1" location="C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/app/controllers/editing_member_jobs_controller.rb:120"/>
6616: Processing in control: start
6616: Starting: running program script
before C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/script/../config/boot
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
after C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/script/../config/boot
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.12 application starting on http://127.0.0.1:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:78.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:123.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:78.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:123.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#installation_path is deprecated, use base_dir. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#installation_path called from C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:93.
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- java
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/lib/start_scheduler.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/config/environments/development.rb:7:in `block in load_environment'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `eval'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `block in load_environment'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:379:in `load_environment'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:137:in `process'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/config/environment.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/script/server:5:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with ruby debug? What's in gui/lib/start_scheduler.rb ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug with RubyMine, remove all debugging-related gems from your Gemfile and don't require them anywhere. RubyMine's debugger doesn't need any support from your project, and it's possible that including debugging stuff in your project could break RubyMine's debugger, perhaps due to version clashes. (I believe the ruby-debug gem works only with Ruby 1.8, and I see you're using 1.9.)